# A UISwitch that is never off

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiswitch

I created a UISwitch with the following code:

```
CGRect switchFrame = CGRectMake(200, 10, 94, 27);
UISwitch *yesNo = [[[UISwitch alloc] initWithFrame:switchFrame] autorelease];
[yesNo addTarget:self action:@selector(handleSwitch:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
```

However, no matter the state of the switch the `on` property always returns `YES`, even when it's visually `NO`.

The event handler looks like this:

```
-(IBAction) handleSwitch: (UISwitch *) sender{
    self.displayCompleted = sender.on;
}
```

Which sets the displayCompleted property:

```
-(void) setDisplayCompleted:(BOOL)newValue{
    displayCompleted = newValue;
    [[self tableView] reloadData];
}
```

What might be causing this?

Comment: I don't think the code you've provided has any issues. What about the `-handleSwitch:` method or the part where you are actually retrieving the state of the switch?

Comment: I just included the event handler as well as the property it sets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was making a stupid mistake: when recreating the cell after reloadData the UISwitch was created without reflecting the current state of the displayCompleted property.